# Airflow | Run task on it's own schedule

Tags: python, airflow

Does anyone have an idea on how to schedule a specific task to trigger on it's own independent time, irrespective of what is set up under `schedule_interval`?

I have a DAG that runs every hour and does at least 7 different tasks. I want to add an 8th task in the middle so it runs at 1AM. The idea behind is that I want this task to fully validate the hourly output that I got throughout the day.

More details:

> I have a DAG that is getting a response from an API request on the
> hourly basis. These metrics will update as the day goes by, but at 1AM
> the following day, I want to run a task that grabs all the metrics from
> the previous day to formally "close" and will also give me reassurance
> that the previous day metrics are accurate. It'll be ideal to have it
> in the same DAG since I'm using the other tasks to populate a DB with
> the extracted data.

```
task_1 hourly
task_2 hourly
task_3 hourly
task_4 daily
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if you can have a task at the end of a DAG which only executes at 1AM each day while all of the other tasks run hourly?

Comment: It won't be at the end, it'll at the beginning:
`check_time >> extract_ads >> facebook_ads >> normalize_csv >>`
`check_time >> extract_ads_1AM >> facebook_ads_1AM >> normalize_csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [ShortCircuitOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/shortcircuitoperator) could be used to fulfill this use case.

Create a function which retrieves the current time and checks against the desired time to execute "task_4", in this case 1AM.  Let's say return `True` if the hour is 1AM and `False` if not.  Put this `ShortCircuitOperator` task before "task_4" in your DAG. Only if the function returns `True` will "task_4" execute; otherwise "task_4" will be skipped and the DAG completes.

`task_1 >> task_2 >> task_3 >> short_circuit_task >> task_4`

Comment: I was looking around and ShortCircuit skips all downstream tasks. If you are reusing some of the tasks that are shared within the 2 use cases, then you can add `trigger_rule = 'none_failed',` to the task that you want to have run irrespective of ShortCircuit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python Schedule to do this: just to cancel this job after it was implemented at 1AM.

```
import schedule
import time

def job_that_executes_once():
    # Do some work that only needs to happen once...
    return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every().day.at('22:30').do(job_that_executes_once)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

See documentations [here](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#cancel-a-job).

And there is another way. Add a **date object** that only contains year,month and day into that function. Default is empty object, if the current date is not the same as the date object, put the current date into that date object. If the current date is same as the date object, ignore this run. And every time when you call that task, just check whether this condition is met.

Comment: You are saying, have the task within the DAG call the function every hour, but within the function only run it if it's 1AM and if it's not then skip it as a whole and keep going to the next task?
Also, how will it work if the function is getting called from a DAG that is scheduled at the top of the hour? By the time it reaches the specific task it might not be 1AM.
EG: Task_4 when it gets executed, it might already be 1:02AM (time varies depending on other dependencies).

Comment: There is one way, inside that task function, you can add a indicator which reset it's value every day. And use that indicator to decide whether to change the value.

Comment: I added another way via using the date object.